# how can I import all python classes in a folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

This is the current structure of my project.

```
   cities
       newyork.py
       london.py
       berlin.py
   main.py
   requirements.txt
```

Each of the city files contains a class. For instance `Class Newyork:` is defined in `newyork.py`

In my `main.py` I am importing all the classes for use in this manner:

```
from cities.newyork import NewYork
from cities.london import London
from cities.berlin import Berlin
```

**What I would like:**
To have something like this

```
from cities.* import NewYork, London, Berlin.
```

Is this possible in python?

Comment: No.  The `import` and `from/import` statements must mention a specific file.  Now, you COULD put a `__init__.py` inside of `cities` that imports the specific classes you need. then have `from cities import *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to `cities/__init__.py` (creating the file if necessary):

```
from newyork import NewYork
from london import London
from berlin import Berlin
```

Then you can write

```
from cities import NewYork, London, Berlin
```